# AttributeError: partially initialized module 'first_window' has no attribute 'InitialWindow' (most likely due to a circular import)

Tags: python, class, tkinter

I'm working on tkinter where I want to close current window and open a new one after clicking the button and vice-versa but getting circular import error.

**main.py file :-**

```
import requests
import first_window

sorted_data = {
    "title": searched_movie['Title'],
    "year": searched_movie['Year'],
    "rated": searched_movie['Rated'],
    "runtime": searched_movie['Runtime'],
    "genre": searched_movie['Genre'],
    "plot": searched_movie['Plot'],
    "language": searched_movie['Language'],
    "starring": searched_movie['Actors'],
    "imdb": searched_movie['imdbRating']
}

first_window.InitialWindow()
```

**first_window.py code :-**

```
from tkinter import Tk, Button, Label, Entry
import second_window


class InitialWindow:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = Tk()
        self.window.title('Movie and Series Info')
        self.window.config(padx=50, pady=50, bg='black')

        # Button
        self.search_button = Button(text="Search", command=self.search)
        self.search_button.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky='ew', pady=12, columnspan=2)

        self.window.mainloop()

    def search(self):
        self.window.destroy()
        second_window.MainWindow()
```

**second_window.py code:-**

```
from tkinter import Tk, Button, Label
import main
import first_window


class MainWindow:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = Tk()
        self.window.title('Movie and Series Info')
        self.window.config(padx=50, pady=50, bg='black')

        # Button
        self.home_button = Button(text="Home", command=self.home)
        self.home_button.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky='ew', pady=12, columnspan=2)

        self.window.mainloop()

    def home(self):
        self.window.destroy()
        first_window.InitialWindow()
```

It's working fine when I'm removing `import main` from second_window.py but I want to use sorted_data from main.py. what can I do, I tried many solutions but nothing worked.

Comment: You could place `sorted_data` into a file by itself so you don't need to import `main` in `second_window.py`. Or you could pass the data in to the window objects when you create them.

Comment: @kemp I'm using api that's why I placed it in main.py and for passing data in window object, I wanted that data in second_window.py but I have created the object it in first_window.py.

Comment: I don't understand your comment about using an API causing a restriction. For passing it to the object, you can pass it to `InitialWindow` and then that passes it to `MainWindow`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move `first_window.InitialWindow()` inside `if __name__ == "__main__":` in `main.py`:

```py
import requests
import first_window

sorted_data = {
    "title": searched_movie['Title'],
    "year": searched_movie['Year'],
    "rated": searched_movie['Rated'],
    "runtime": searched_movie['Runtime'],
    "genre": searched_movie['Genre'],
    "plot": searched_movie['Plot'],
    "language": searched_movie['Language'],
    "starring": searched_movie['Actors'],
    "imdb": searched_movie['imdbRating']
}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    first_window.InitialWindow()
```

Then `first_window.InitialWindow()` will not be executed by `import main`.

If `first_window` is used only in that line, you can move `import first_window` into the `if` block as well.